# Error displaying data into a input text field

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having a problem trying to display the data into a input field, instead of display What is on the database it display ' `$row[coursename]` ', the one that is on the `<td>` works fine.

Any ideas of How to fix this, I'm really new with php

```
<?php
 require("coneccion.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
  header("Location: index.php");
  die("Redirecting to index.php");
}

$query = "SELECT courseid, coursename, id FROM courses where courseid = 179";

try
{
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
  die("Error");
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th> 
  </tr> 
  <?php 
  foreach($rows as $row):   
    echo "<tr>";

      echo '<td><a href="#">' . htmlentities($row['coursename'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</a></td>';
      echo '<input type="text" name="coursename" value=" $row[coursename] " />';
      echo '</tr>';

    endforeach;
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the variable outside of the string:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="coursename" value="' .htmlentities($row['coursename']) . '" />';
```

You can't add double quotes around it without also adding brackets (but that invovles a lot of error-prone escaping)

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"coursename\" value=\"{htmlentities($row['coursename'])}\" />";
```

Comment: Thanks you this options works, but it give a warning Notice: Use of undefined constant coursename

Comment: @CarlosPerez see updates - you need strings in your array indexes

Comment: why are you using '\' before ", sorry im really new at this

Comment: When one starts a string with `"`, PHP expects the string to end at the next `"`.  Adding a \ before the `"` says "Hey, don't end the string here"

Comment: Did you know why if a remove foreach($rows as $row): the code stop working

Comment: @CarlosPerez That sounds like a different question

Comment: Yep!  Feel free to post a new question about that section with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="coursename" value=" '.htmlentities($row['coursename']).' " />';
```

Comment: That opens up XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: indeed, added htmlentities